# number of pairs that are member of a class of one of the given partitions

Tags: combinatorics, set-partition

Suppose I am given a set of S partition of universal set A, define pair as (a,b) iff elements a,b are members of one of set in at least one partition. I want to know how many pairs in S.
Example:
$$A = \{1,2,3,4,5\}$$
$$S = \{
s_1=\{\{1,2\},\{3,4,5\}\},
s_2=\{\{1\},\{2,3,4,5\}\},
s_3=\{\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{4,5\}\}
\}$$
Pairs:
(1,2)
(2,3)
(2,4)
(2,5)
(3,4)
(3,5)
(4,5)
Number of pairs = 7
Is there an algorithm that takes less than $O(n^2)$,
$n=|A|$ or correct keywords or name of this problem?

Comment: I’d be very much surprised if there were an algorithm better than $O(n^2)$.

Comment: Thanks for comment! May be you know if this problem has name or some keywords that helps me to find some article, may be find algorithm that better in some conditions?

Comment: Basically what you’re looking for is the union of the equivalence relations defined by the partitions. It wouldn’t surprise me if it had come up often enough to have some literature, but it’s far enough outside my own field that I don’t really know, I’m afraid.

Comment: Thanks a lot, found some addition information, thats not exactly what i'm looking for, but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20154368/union-find-implementation-using-python